# Is there a way to remove tabs inside panels?

Tags: 7, panels

This is a simple question, i know that there are many modules who can alter tab like [tab tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer).

But i would like to avoid to install another module in my site because he's already slow and my server he's limited, it's why i'm asking this question.

I alter the `user template profile`, so i just want to remove the tabs : `view and edit`, i didn't find any setting to do that but maybe i missed something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, I believe the answer is no, because the tabs are rendered outside of the area that Panels is responsible for.

If you use [Panels everywhere](http://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere), then you can simply leave the tabs out however, "In panels". If you don't, the rendering is probably happening in page.tpl.php instead.

Comment: Yes, you're right, tabs are rendered outside panels, so i thinks it's impossible like you said. I never used `Panels everywhere` and for this projet i don't have the time to test it (but i will for others) Thxs